# AWS Cloudwatch queries Full event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

So I am trying to write AWS Cloudwatch queries to show information of only when sensitive actions occur in a S3 bucket. Therefore I want to filter on the event name. Do you know where I can get the FULL list of all the event names on S3 such as PUTOBJECT and etc. This is so I can select what to filter on

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [S3 API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations.html) for that.

But for some events, such as PutObject, you will need to create CloudTrial trial and log data level operations.